# Is it possible to remote debug a VirtualBox with visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, virtualbox, remote-debugging

I'm running different versions of our application on Sun's open source [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), is it possible to remote debug the app from the host OS with Visual Studio? The problem is that in Visual Studio when I want to attach to a remote machine I have to enter either a computer name or IP and the IP I get from within the virtual box isn't pingable from the host machine.

I'm primarily interested in debugging native code (so I can run with no authentication) but if there's a way to debug managed code too please let me know.

I should note that the host OS is Vista and the guest is XP.

---

Thanks to Mark I got things working, I'll note all the steps I had to take for future reference:

1. Change the VM network from `NAT` to `Bridged Adapter` (have to power off the VM first)
2. In the guest OS change the default security setting to `Classic - local users authenticate as themselves` as [described here](http://kbalertz.com/833900/debug-computers-running-Windows-Workgroup-Visual-Studio.aspx):

   - `Control Panel ->  Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy`
   - `Local Policies -> Security Options`
   - Change `Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts` to **Classic - local users authenticate as themselves**
3. Reboot guest OS
4. Disabled [the firewall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283673) on the guest OS

   - If `msvsmon` can't do it by itself
   - `firewall.cpl`

Comment: I don't understand the moving parts here: The application (the one you want to debug) is running on the guest os, Visual Studio on the host, the host cannot ping the guest? then who can? you need to have some form of communication between then.

Comment: I found that "Classic - local users authenticate as themselves" was already enabled but still unable to connect. I changed this setting and then changed it back again and it worked.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It sounds like your guest setting have NAT for the netowking adapter.  Go into the guest setting, choose networking and if the type of network is NAT switch it to Bridged.  NAT produces an address range that is not public; whereas, bridged will give the guest OS an IP on the same subnet as the host.