# Home-Brew Server Farm and Remote Debugging

Tags: c#, windows, debugging, dns, vmware

I want to create a home-brew server farm, hosted on my own Windows 7 x64 box.  There would be three guest 2k8 Servers, one each to run IIS, a domain controller, and SQL Server 2k8 R2.  All guest machines would belong to a domain.  The host machine is in a workgroup (not in a domain), and has Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed.

I want to know:

1. Can I remote debug (from the host machine in a workgroup) managed code on the guest OS (which is in a domain)?

   1. Any complications if I'm using VirtualBox?  I see a [similar topic elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584939/is-it-possible-to-remote-debug-a-virtualbox-with-visual-studio), but it does not address the domain issue.
2. Can I use the VMWare Workstation "integrated virtual debugger" to do the same (debug managed code on guest OS)?  Has VMWare started supporting this in VS 2010 yet?

Either way I need to take into account the workgroup-accessing-domain story I'd be dealing with.

Comment: @AakashM, this isn't a programming question I'll admit, but its hard to say who best to answer such a question - a handful of programmers are much more likely to be able to answer this question than a handful of server admin I would think?  Plus, the related topic linked had no issues being posted on SO despite probably leaning more towards server than this one

Comment: @Smudge yes I agree it's not clear cut

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remote debug the guest OS's.  Take a look at [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f.aspx) for information on cross-domain remote debugging, which I believe still applies with the host not actually being on a domain.  You simply ignore the fact either machine is on a domain and create like for like local accounts on the machines - all described in the aforementioned MSDN article.

If that creates problems for you, you can also disable authentication which seems to be a popular choice, despite being insecure:
http://communities.vmware.com/message/1617741

The article you linked in your post solves any networking issues so between that and the above you should be able to get the remote debugger up and running.

Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402108/does-anyone-know-where-or-how-i-get-the-vmware-visual-studio-plugin-installed) and answer any use regarding question 2?  I can't find anywhere a mention that the integrated VM remote debugger is actually available for 2010, but then I can't find any posts complaining that it isn't.  Perhaps it's just a closely guarded secret!?

EDI #19 or so:

Unfortunately I've found [this article](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/282407) complaining that VS2010 isn't support by VSID. =(

Good luck!